# Access a image control in another page, class windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Can access an `control (image)` from another class in `C#`, `XAML`?
For example: In class A (image) is collapsed/hidden, when check if image is collapsed/hidden in class B, i want to be visible/enabled, it's possible?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PhoneApplicationService` to do it.

For example:
Suppose you navigated from `class A` to `class B`.
In `class B`, before you navigate back to class A, set

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["showImage"] = true;
```

In `class A`, implement `OnNavigatedTo` to handle it:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("showImage"))
    {
        bool showImage = (bool)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["showImage"];
        if (showImage)
        {
            this.YourImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            this.YourImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("showImage");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For multiple images, you can try the following approach:

In `class B`, instead of passing a `bool` to the `PhoneApplicationService`, pass a `Dictionary` of bools, each one representing the state of a image:

```
var showImage = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
showImage[1] = true;
showImage[2] = false;
showImage[3] = true;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["showImage"] = showImage;
```

In `class A`, create a dictionary for your images:

```
private Dictionary<int, Image> _images = new Dictionary<int, Image>();
```

Then in its constructor, fill the dictionaries with your Images:

```
InitializeComponent();

_images[1] = YourImage1;
_images[2] = YourImage2;
_images[3] = YourImage3;
```

In `class A`'s `OnNavigatedTo`, do:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("showImage"))
    {
        var showImage = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["showImage"] as Dictionary<int, bool>;
        if (showImage != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in showImage.Keys)
            {
                if (_images.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    if (showImage[key])
                    {
                        _images[key].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _images[key].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you prefer, you can change the **key** of the dictionaries for a more representative string.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, works almost perfectly,
because if for example we have a list of multiple objects and want to display images only for those containing some value:
Object 1 2 3 4 5 6
Show image for object 2 4 6
a solution, I tried with instruction for each and which contains x, the image will be visible.

Comment: any update? to show image only if some items are marked

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in class B, I make some checks with my items, if some value equals with a condition, makes my image visible. I put a screenshot to explain very well what I want to do.

Comment: Is there a application that already does that? Just for me to understand better your situation. :)

Comment: yes, exist an app on android, but in windows phone not works, if I have two item wrong need to show two warnning  picture see example.